# How do I build this java project with maven?

Tags: java, maven, open-source

I honestly don't know anything about java, I'm just trying to build the latest version of this project to try and work around bugs in the version that is packaged by my OS. The project in question:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxguitar/

I tried running `mvn compile`, `mvn clean package`, and `mvn clean install` but no jar file was produced in the source tree. The readme has no instructions for building. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `mvn clean install`?

Answer (score 1):

To produce jar you need at least `package` phase, you can get there by doing:

```
mvn clean package
```

(`clean` is to remove stale data, it is a good practice to use it always with maven) and you jar will be in `target` directory.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like `mvn clean package` doesn't build a jar either.

Answer (score 0):

mvn complite just complite the project and no package.
answer : mvn clean package.this will clean,complite and package the project,after finished, you can found the package(jar or war) into the $PROJECT_HOME/target/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I usually run `mvn clean install` - which in addition will add the built jar into your local maven artifact repository.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't build a jar either.

Comment: Does the mvn job complete successfully or is there an error? If it's a success, is there a 'target' folder that gets created within the folder with the built jar inside?